# Conditional formitting Excel - How to check if the cell in the row above is of lower value - without specifying exact row (= for any row)

Tags: conditional-formatting

How can we make a cell red if it svalue is higher than the cell in the row above.

But this without specifying the exact row of the cell. That is: so that it works for any cell. So it should work for a cell in row 5 (check for cell above in row 4), but also for row 25 (check for cell above in row 24), etc.?

*Edit: can we also add please one more addition, which is: to check if the cell above is the cell B10. If yes: don't apply the conditional formatting. If no: apply the conditional formatting.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative cell references.

Create a new formatting rule with a formula. Your active cell must be at least in row 2, because there is no row above row 1. Let's say your current cell is B2. You can now type the formula

```
=B2>B1
```

The cell references in this formula are **relative**. They contain no $ signs. If instead of typing, you click to select the cells when you write the formula in the box, Excel will put $ signs into the reference (like `$B$2>$B$1`). References with $ signs are absolute and always refer to the same cell, but references without $ signs are relative to the current cell position.

Example: If the current cell is B2 then the formula's B2 means "the current cell" and the relative reference to B1 means "the cell one row up from the current cell". When you apply the same conditional format to the next ten rows, then cell B5 will also use a comparison of "the current cell" with "the cell one row up from the current cell".

You can select several cells at once before creating the conditional formatting rule, but you must keep in mind that the currently active cell will be the point of reference for any relative cell reference in the formula.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: To keep the formula referencing just one cell directly, use `=B2>OFFSET(B2;-1;0)`, possibly wrapped  in `IFERROR(...;True/False)` for a default True or False

Comment: @teylyn This works great than you! Can I ask you one more addition? I will accept anyway, but would be nice if we could check if the cell above is B10 or not. If yes: don't apply the formatting. If no: apply the formatting.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If you only want the formula to work if the cell above is B10, then by definition, put the conditional format into B11. Or do you want the formula to always refer to cell B10? Then use $B$10 as the reference. Absolute references don't change.

Comment: @Hannu What purpose does the complicated Offset serve? Why would you want to jump through these Offset hoops to reference the cell above, if it can be done just with `=B2>B1`?? There is no benefit whatsoever in using Offset here. Unless you revel in the academic exercise to write ony one cell reference. Of course, that could be applied to any formula that uses any relative reference. Are you suggesting Offset for all other cell references, too, in order to keep only one cell reference visible in the formula? That's really weird

Comment: One benefit: if you have large sets of cells and use e.g Autofilter and insert and delete rows - then I believe the "complicated" thingie above "survives" better in conditional formatting on those cells. With the simpler form of reference the conditional format settings get split up haphazardly, more often -> so less problems.